# Migration from nuxt2 to nuxt3

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

So I'm a noob in nuxt. Basically there is just this one file that was written for Nuxt 2, now it needs to be made compatible with Nuxt 3. Index.ts file.

```js
import { Nuxt } from '@nuxt/core';
import { BundleBuilder } from '@nuxt/webpack';
import { Builder } from '@nuxt/builder';
import { config } from '../../client/nuxt.config';
//import config from './nuxt.config';

export default class NuxtServer {
  public nuxt: Nuxt;

  public async run(shouldBuild: boolean = true): Nuxt {
    const nuxt = new Nuxt(config);

    // Build only in dev mode
    if (config.dev && shouldBuild) {
      const builder = new Builder(nuxt, BundleBuilder);
      const res = await builder.build();

      this.nuxt = res.nuxt;

      return res.nuxt;
    }

    if (this.nuxt) {
      return this.nuxt;
    }
    return nuxt;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the error/not working? You could create a brand new Nuxt3 project and check the content there, then try to copy it in your current file. Nuxt3 is using Vite by default, and not Webpack (as a reminder).

Comment: Well it's actually from a client, I usually work on only backend, but this is the only file he provided. I have to make sure that this will work with nuxt 3.

Comment: My previous comment is still valid.

Comment: @kissu  Issue has been mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71500292/using-nuxt-3-with-nest

Comment: @kissu Here is the link of the repo which shows exactly what you said. created in nuxt 3. tried to build. But not having way to serve them from nest route. https://github.com/hnviradiya/nest-nuxt