# using Nuxt 3 with Nest

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

Currently we are able to build nuxt as following. But are unable to handle routes. We basically want to serve nuxt app from Nestjs.

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module.js';
import { loadNuxt } from 'nuxt3';
import { buildNuxt,  Resolver } from '@nuxt/kit';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  // Check if we need to run Nuxt in development mode
  const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

  // Get a ready to use Nuxt instance
  const nuxt = await loadNuxt({ rootDir: 'src/client-app/' })

  // Enable live build & reloading on dev
  if (isDev) {
    buildNuxt(nuxt)
  }

  await app.listen(3001);
}
bootstrap();
```

Following is next (react) equivalent code which is working and trying to achieve in Nuxt 3.

```
https://github.com/hnviradiya/contact-list/blob/e38a72167d5710fcc9f3ed9718fa9bfe8ebb7d00/src/server/client-app/client-app.service.ts#L25

import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { IncomingMessage, ServerResponse } from 'http';
import createServer, { NextServer } from 'next/dist/server/next';

@Injectable()
export class ClientAppService {
  private nextServer: NextServer;

  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {}

  async onModuleInit(): Promise<void> {
    try {
      this.nextServer = createServer({
        dev: this.configService.get<string>('NODE_ENV') !== 'production',
        dir: './src/client',
      });
      await this.nextServer.prepare();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  handler(req: IncomingMessage, res: ServerResponse) {
    return this.nextServer.getRequestHandler()(req, res);
  }
}
```

In nuxt 2 there were `nuxt.render(req, res)` or `nuxt.renderRoute(route, context)`. But these methods are not available in nuxt3.

https://nuxtjs.org/docs/internals-glossary/nuxt/

So how to serve nuxt app through NestJs.

Following is the repo where nuxt 3 code is there but it is not serving nuxt app.

https://github.com/hnviradiya/nest-nuxt

Comment: Next/nest/nuxt? All of the 3 names here? Maybe typo'ed some of them here? If NEST is useful, you should probably add this tag in prio.

Comment: It's kinda strange to use Nest with Next/Nuxt, what is the use-case, I'm curious.

Comment: main issue is related to nuxt. because same issue can be with expressjs as well. thing is we are unable to find way to render nuxt app from nestjs (or say expressjs).

Comment: Next I have mentioned to show example. example of what we want to achieve which can be achieved using Next (and we have achieved that in nuxt 2 as well in similar fashion. Only issue is nuxt 3 is not having enough documentation or I am unable to find one)

Comment: Usecase is. We want to keep single repo/server to serve both nuxt app and api data. so for route starting with '/api' we serve data. From rest of the route, we serve nuxt app through nestjs itself.

Answer (score 0):

while Nestjs is a **great** server, it's angular style @decorators and modular setup is too unlike Nuxt3's scaffold simplicity.

This conception feels like a bad idea.